# ExpandableListAdapter gives wrong output

Tags: android, expandablelistadapter

I have created `ExpandableListAdapter` by [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) (many thanks!) for sorting products into groups. But I had to do some mistake, bacause some products are in wrong group, some products are in many groups and some products are not even visible (showed).

Below is `ExpandableListAdapter` and code for filling data into `Map<String, List<Product>>` (for products) and `List<String>` (for groups).

Adapter:

```
class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private Map<String, List<Product>> _listDataChild;
    private boolean viewOnly;
    private Config config;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
            Map<String, List<Product>> listChildData, boolean viewOnly, Config config) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        this.viewOnly = viewOnly;
        this.config = config;
        /*
         * THIS GIVES ME RIGHT PAIRS (GROUP : PRODUCT)
         *

        int y = 0;
        int i = 1;

        for (Entry<String, List<Product>> entry : this._listDataChild.entrySet()) {
              String key = entry.getKey();
              List<Product> value = entry.getValue();
              for(Product valuee : value){
                  Log.v("PRODUCTS list", i + " GROUP: " + key + " VALUE: " + valuee.getName());
                  Log.v("GROUPS list", i + " GROUP: " + this._listDataHeader.get(y) + " VALUE: " + valuee.getName());
                  i++;
              }
              y++;

        }
        */

    }


    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Product product = (Product) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.product_item, null);

            CheckBox name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_item_checkbox);
            TextView price_value = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_item_price_value);
            TextView price_value_vo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_item_price_value_vo);
            TextView price_textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_item_price_textview);
            DatePicker from = (DatePicker) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_item_datePicker_from);
            EditText serial_number = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_item_edittext);
            serial_number.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcherCustom(product));
            TextView item_lenght = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_item_lenght);
            TextView item_lenght_vo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_item_lenght_vo);
            TextView item_type = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_item_type); 
            TextView item_type_vo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_item_type_vo);
            TextView name_only = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_item_name);

            name.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() { 
                public void onClick(View v) { 
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ; 
                    Product product = (Product) cb.getTag(); 
                    product.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                } 
            }); 


            DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener mDateListenerFrom = new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    Product product = (Product) view.getTag(); 
                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    Date date = new Date(year - 1900,monthOfYear,dayOfMonth);
                    product.setFrom(date);
                }
            };

            Calendar cal = product.getActive_toDate();
            if (cal == null){
               cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            }
            Date date = new Date(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900,cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            from.setMinDate(date.getTime());
            from.init(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), mDateListenerFrom);
            product.setFrom(date);


           //quantity.setTag(product);  
           name.setTag(product);
           from.setTag(product);
           name.setChecked(product.getSelected());
           name.setText(product.getName());
           name_only.setText(product.getName());
           name_only.setVisibility(8);
           item_lenght_vo.setVisibility(8);
           item_type_vo.setVisibility(8);
           price_value.setText(product.getPrice());
           price_value_vo.setText(product.getPrice());
           price_value_vo.setVisibility(8);            

           if (product.getUnit().compareTo("hardware") == 0){
               from.setVisibility(DatePicker.INVISIBLE);
               serial_number.setVisibility(EditText.VISIBLE);
               serial_number.setText(product.getSerial_number());
               item_lenght_vo.setText(product.getUnit());
               item_lenght.setText(product.getUnit());
               item_type.setText("Serial number");
           }else{
               serial_number.setVisibility(DatePicker.INVISIBLE);
               from.setVisibility(EditText.VISIBLE);
               if (config.getConfig_change_sales_date().compareTo("0") == 0){
                   from.setEnabled(false);
               }
               item_lenght.setText(product.getUnit_length() + " " + product.getUnit());
               item_lenght_vo.setText(product.getUnit_length() + " " + product.getUnit());
               item_type.setText("Product start");
           }

           if (viewOnly){   
               name_only.setVisibility(0);
               name.setVisibility(8);
               from.setVisibility(8);                
               serial_number.setVisibility(8);
               item_type_vo.setVisibility(0);
               item_type.setVisibility(8);
               item_lenght.setVisibility(8);
               item_lenght_vo.setVisibility(0);
               item_lenght_vo.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
               price_value.setVisibility(8);
               price_value_vo.setVisibility(0);
               price_value_vo.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
               price_textview.setVisibility(8); 
               historyButton.setVisibility(8);

               // Height adjustment of product box
               convertView.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(ListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  


               // backButton to the whole width
               backButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f));


               //  Set the same width
               Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
               @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
               int width = display.getWidth();

               name_only.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED,MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
               item_lenght_vo.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED,MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);


               if(name_only.getMeasuredWidth() < item_lenght_vo.getMeasuredWidth()) {
                   name_only.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(item_lenght_vo.getMeasuredWidth(), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
               }
               else {
                   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rl = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(name_only.getMeasuredWidth(), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                   rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.product_item_name);
                   rl.topMargin = 10;
                   item_lenght_vo.setLayoutParams(rl);
               };

               RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
               params.setMargins(70, 0, 0, 0);
               params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.product_item_name);
               item_type_vo.setLayoutParams(params);
               RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
               params2.setMargins(70, 10, 0, 0);
               params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.product_item_name);
               params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.product_item_name);
               price_value_vo.setLayoutParams(params2);
           };

        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_separator, null);
        }

        TextView group_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_group_name);
        group_name.setText(headerTitle);//product.getGroup_name());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
    }


}
```

Filling data: (there is no problem, everything is clear and works great)

```
public void createProductList(){
      Boolean viewOnly = type.compareTo("Product") == 0 ? true : false;


      try {
          product = products.get(0);    
          // ArrayList<Map<String,List<Product>> products
          // Map<String,List<Product> product
          for(Entry<String, List<Product>> entry: product.entrySet()){
              String key = entry.getKey();
              groups.add(key);         
              // List<String>
          }
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("MSG", e.toString());
      }

      dataAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this,groups,product,viewOnly,config);
      // Assign adapter to ListView
      productList.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
  }
```

The `Adapter` is okay, works well, no error exception, just wrong sorting into groups. I don't know what's wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `listDataHeader` and `listChildData` are correctly storing their data, I'd say the problem is with your `getChildView()` method.  It's fairly complex and hard to determine but it appears you are doing the following:

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        //Inflating, setting listeners, filling with data
    }

    //I don't see anything being done when the convertView is not null?
}
```

You should be doing:

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        //Inflating
    }

    //setting listeners, filling with data
}
```

I could be wrong and you are doing that. It's hard to tell in the posting.  This is where an IDE is useful.

Side note, you should be using the ViewHolder paradigm. It'll greatly help with performance and should almost always be a must for any adapter implementation. Here's a [brief run down and example](http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/05/22/simple-android-developer-mistakes/). It's towards the bottom of the blog posting.